# Advanced currency feature is effect for child object of opportunity object?

Tags: opportunity, multi-currency, currencytype

When we enable advanced currency feature is it effect for currency fields on the child object of the opportunity object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the currency you choose in the Opportunity is applied to all child objects. Unfortunately I couldn't find the docs that state this, but having implemented solutions with Multi-Currency, I know this to be true.

Comment: Is it applicable for Dated Exchange Rates also?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Currency Mgt is in effect for all objects with Currency fields

The dated Exchange Rates, however, are only enabled for select objects:

> Dated exchange rates are used for opportunities, opportunity products,
>   opportunity product schedules, campaign opportunity fields,
>   opportunity splits, and reports related to these objects and fields.
>   Dated exchange rates are not used in forecasting, currency fields in
>   other objects, or currency fields in other types of reports.

Thus, on all objects other than the above, the exchange rates in effect are always the most recent exchange rates, and not necessarily the exchange rate in effect as of the custom object's someDateFld__c